# Angular 5 - implementing finally on subscribe

Tags: angular, refresh, subscribe

I am writing an app with Angular 5.

I am working on using the ion-refresher to refresh the page and I want to cancel the spinner if there is either an error or a success back so essentially a finally block.

I need the refresh to stop spinning and go back to the default position in any outcome (success or error).

How can I achieve this with my code? This is what I have tried and I get an error:

html

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="refresh($event)"></ion-refresher>
        <div *ngIf="data">
         {{ data }}
        </div>
</ion-content>
```

component

```js
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    data: any;

    constructor(private userInfoService: UserInfoService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.userInfoService
            .getEmployeeInfo()
            .subscribe((response) => {
              this.data = response;
            });
    }

    refresh(event) {

        this.userInfoService
            .getEmployeeInfo()
            //.pipe(
              //.finally(() => event.complete())
            //)
            .subscribe((response) => {
              this.data = response;
              event.complete(); //this works but what if there was an error
            })
            //.finally(() => event.complete());
            //Property 'finally' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `subscribe`:

```js
someObservable.subscribe(
  (response) => {
      // do something when data is received
      console.log(response);
  }),
  (err) => {
      // do something on error
      console.error(err)
  },
  () => {
      // do something when operation successfully complete
      console.log('success!);
});
```

Comment: I could not get the last block to run... :( nevermind you have to put the err block too even if i don't need it

Comment: @user1261710 - Could you call `event.complete()` in the error block also?

Comment: I guess I could but it's nicer if you don't have to repeat code.

Comment: The last (3rd) callback doesn't get called.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ad `finalize` instead of `finally` before `subscribe` method.

```
.getEmployeeInfo()
            .pipe(finalize(() => { 
               event.complete()
             }))
```

and yes, without a dot `.` This will help you

Comment: I got this error:             Argument expression expected.

      L40:  .getEmployeeInfo()
      L41:  .pipe(finally(() => event.complete()))
      L42:  .subscribe(

            '{' expected.

Comment: sine your event compete returning nothing just wrap it in brackets, i will edit it in a second

Comment: Nah, I still got an error: [16:40:51]  typescript: 
            Argument expression expected.

      L40:  .getEmployeeInfo()
      L41:  .pipe(finally(() => {
      L42:     event.complete();

            '{' expected.

Comment: this.userInfoService
            .getEmployeeInfo()
            .pipe(finally(() => {
               event.complete();
             }))
            .subscribe(
              (response) => { this.data = response; }
            );

Comment: delete this `;` after event.complete and use ` finalize` instead of finally, or try both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178552/discussion-between-kraken-and-user1261710).